# Как запросить один параметр из строки параметров, разделенных & амперсандом?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка 'st.cmd=friendMain&st.friendId=123456789&st.layer.cmd=PopLayerClose&st._forceSetHistory=true'
нужно из нее вытащить параметр friendId. Можно ли это сделать изящнее чем регэкспами?

Comment: Есть современные методы, смотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/6766879

Comment: Какой регэксы если есть нативные функции работы с урл строкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let friendId = new URL('http://localhost/?st.cmd=friendMain&st.friendId=123456789&st.layer.cmd=PopLayerClose&st._forceSetHistory=true').searchParams.get('st.friendId');
console.log(friendId);
```